# when, or where, to create mongo indexes in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, indexing

In a ASP.net WebApi application - when, or where, would it be best to create mongodb indexes?

- As part of the deployment process?
- Application startup?
- Before every query that would benefit from the index?
- cron job outside of application?

As far as I understand, there is little overhead in calling `CreateIndex` if the index already exist. It want be recreated or anything, but still...

Comment: Mongo is different from typical relational databases. There is no formal schema. There is no formal point in time where the database is transitioned from one form to another.